How can I display `n` lines in JavaScript without loading the entire file?
You have a multi-select file upload, and the goal is to display each file's content in chunks of n lines, rather than loading the entire file at once, to prevent browser slowdowns or crashes.
<input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFileMultiple" name="uploadLogFile" multiple onchange="uploadFiles(event)" required>
<pre id='output'></pre>

Please let me know if there are better approaches to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!
My approach : I am getting the files in loop , loading whole file using file loader and displaying the data.
const uploadLogFiles = async (event) => {
    var resData = ''
    const fileLen = event.target.files.length

    // Convert the FileList into an array and iterate
    let files = Array.from(event.target.files).map(file => {
        // Define a new file reader
        let reader = new FileReader();
        // Create a new promise
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            reader.fileName = file.name
            reader.onload = function (evt) {
                resultData = `<label class="form-label">File Name - ${evt.target.fileName}</label>
                                         <pre style='max-height: 10em;'>${evt.target.result}</pre>`
                resolve(resultData);
            };
            // Read the file as a text
            reader.readAsText(file);

        });
    });
    // At this point you'll have an array of results
    let res = await Promise.all(files);
    for(var l=0; l<res.length; l++){
        resData +=res[l]
    }
    $('#output').html(resData)

}

**Expected Output : **
File Name - file1 
file data .....

File Name - file2 
file data .....

File Name - file3
file data .....


AFAIK, you can't do this in the browser. You have to load the whole file.
